Too many udev events when docking station is plugged in
My laptop has only two USB-C ports, no HDMI. This is why I use a docking station to connect my external monitor (monitor <-> HDMI <-> docking station <-> USB-C <-> laptop).
When I unplug the docking station, the monitor turns black (as expected). But when I plug the docking station in, I have to wait for about 13 or 14 seconds before I see my desktop.
These are the udev event for unplugging:
$ udevadm monitor -s drm
monitor will print the received events for:
UDEV - the event which udev sends out after rule processing
KERNEL - the kernel uevent

KERNEL[5283.373093] change   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/drm/card1 (drm)
UDEV  [5283.375277] change   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/drm/card1 (drm)

When I plug the docking station in, I get more events:
$ udevadm monitor -s drm
monitor will print the received events for:
UDEV - the event which udev sends out after rule processing
KERNEL - the kernel uevent

KERNEL[5288.949739] change   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/drm/card1 (drm)
UDEV  [5288.950789] change   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/drm/card1 (drm)
KERNEL[5291.019790] change   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/drm/card1 (drm)
UDEV  [5291.020852] change   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/drm/card1 (drm)
KERNEL[5292.460161] change   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/drm/card1 (drm)
UDEV  [5292.463322] change   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/drm/card1 (drm)
KERNEL[5294.443110] change   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/drm/card1 (drm)
UDEV  [5294.444144] change   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/drm/card1 (drm)
KERNEL[5295.909715] change   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/drm/card1 (drm)
UDEV  [5295.912527] change   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/drm/card1 (drm)

I have created this udev rule to get a better understanding of what's happening:
/etc/udev/rules.d/95-hdmi-plug.rules:
ACTION=="change", SUBSYSTEM=="drm", RUN+="/tmp/udev-log"

/tmp/udev-log:
#!/bin/sh
{
    echo
    date '+%Y-%m-%d %H.%M.%S'
    printf 'DP-1 '
    cat /sys/class/drm/card1-DP-1/status
} >> /tmp/log

It looks like the external monitor is connected three times, when I plug in the docking station:
2024-11-12 11.43.09
DP-1 connected

2024-11-12 11.43.11
DP-1 disconnected

2024-11-12 11.43.13
DP-1 connected

2024-11-12 11.43.15
DP-1 disconnected

2024-11-12 11.43.16
DP-1 connected

I'm using Arch Linux (up-to-date) and the dwm window manager.
Any ideas why this happens?
